# Can friends on Battle.net see the date I bought a game?

Tags: battle.net

I bought a game very recently to play with friends, but I told them I already had it. When I add them, can they see the date I bought it, or does it only tell them that I own the game?

Comment: Unless you play the game and make your status visible to your friends they won't even know you have the game

Comment: Oh, okay. So they won't know when I got it, and my secret is safe. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No.

Your friends have no way of seeing when you bought a game or even if you own it, but they can see your playtime and profile on some games (Diablo 3 and Overwatch are some examples from the top of my head) and realize that there's a discrepancy in your story.

Comment: This is not related to Battle.net app itself - people can see your profile and character stats in certain games. In Diablo 3, as mentioned, it is very easy to see how much a person has played by their achievements. But if this is a classic game, like Diablo 2 or older, you are fine :-)

Comment: Well, that's quite alright. I had told them I didn't play it too much.